# SQL left join returns null column

Tags: sql-server, join, null

I am trying to do a `LEFT JOIN` on two tables, where one table has a datetime column, and the other table has a date column. As I am working in SQL Server, I used `CONVERT` to change the datetime to date. I then wrote the join statement:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,db1.dbo.table1.datecolumn), db2.dbo.table2.datecolumn
FROM db1.dbo.table1
LEFT JOIN db2.dbo.table2 
    ON db1.dbo.table1.datecolumn = db2.dbo.table2.datecolumn
```

And the query returns the date column from table1, but the column from table2 is populated with NULL values only. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried `CAST` instead of `CONVERT`, with no luck. Is there something happening with the conversion? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could include example data, or better yet, mock it up using a tool like http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Please give us the DDL of table1, table2. Please also provide a few lines of DML for both tables - or better still, provide a dbfiddle. Take a look [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing the `convert()` in the wrong place I guess. You have to do it in the equals operation of the `ON`, it's still a `datetime` there, regardless of what you do on it in the list of selected columns.

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,db1.dbo.table1.datecolumn), db2.dbo.table2.datecolumn
FROM db1.dbo.table1
LEFT JOIN db2.dbo.table2 
    ON CONVERT(date,db1.dbo.table1.datecolumn) = db2.dbo.table2.datecolumn
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually there's not problem with the `CONVERT` function. The reason that why date's column from `table2` is returning a `NULL`, it's because isn't the preserved side on the `JOIN`.

You're performing a `LEFT JOIN` between `db1.dbo.table1` and `db2.dbo.table2` tables, where the preserved side is `db1.dbo.table1`. Preserved side means that in case the matching condition specified at `ON` clause is evaluated either to 'false' or 'unknown', then column's values from the either left or right table (depends on which `JOIN` you're performing: `LEFT` or `RIGHT`) will be returned, whereas the column's values from the other side will be missing (a `NULL` will be used as placeholder).

Please, take a look at the following picture that shows how `JOIN` operations are represented graphically.

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/visual-representation-of-sql-joins).

I hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

ON db1.dbo.table1.datecolumn = db2.dbo.table2.datecolumn

because you say datecolumn is of type datetime , this is really hard to work. datetime is "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.nnn]" and to have two equal you need to have them equal by millisecond . More exactly by 3 milliseconds distance.

I think you need to convert both here

ON CONVERT(date,db1.dbo.table1.datecolumn) = CONVERT(date,  db2.dbo.table2.datecolumn )