# LEFT JOIN returns NULL in middle of query

Tags: mysql, join, mariadb

Started working recently with joins again and I am trying to get the server name from a different table with matching ID's (Foreign Key).

```
SELECT Website.`services`.`port`,
       Website.`services`.`description`,
       Website.`ips`.`ServerName`,
       Website.`ips`.`ip` 
    FROM Website.`services`
    LEFT JOIN Website.`ips` 
        ON Website.`services`.`id` = Website.`ips`.`id`;
```

However the results are NULL after the first 3 rows which should be the server name and IP instead.

[image: Result of Query]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL left join returns null column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/206532/sql-left-join-returns-null-column)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are no matching records for the those items in the ips table. If you only want records where data is in both tables you may want to change to an inner join. You may also need to check your data to verify that nothing is missing.

[Join Types](http://www.sql-join.com/sql-join-types/)

> Left Join: Select all records from Table A, along with records from Table B for which the join condition is met (if at all).
>
> Inner Join: Select all records from Table A and Table B, where the join condition is met.

Answer (score -2):

After some messing around with the fancy query builder of SQLYog i figured everything out!

```
SELECT `ips`.`ServerName`, `services`.`description`, `services`.`port`, `ips`.`ip`
    FROM `Website`.`services` 
        INNER JOIN `Website`.`ips` 
            ON (`services`.`server` = `ips`.`id`);
```

I just selected the wrong database afterall, and the wrong join.